# Something about the optimizer

Tags: monetdb

1. I create a database and connect with it. But when I execute

```sql
select optimizer;
```

it returns

```sql
SELECT: identifier 'optimizer' unknown
```

What's the problem with it? And I can't find the **sys** table in the database using \d.

2. If I want to add an optimizer myopt, is it enough for the steps below:

   1. write the opt_myopt.h and opt_myopt.c in /monetdb5/optimizer/
   2. Add the code into **codes** in /monetdb5/optimizer/opt_wrapper.c
   3. Add the function into **optimizer_init_funcs** in /monetdb5/optimizer/optimizer.c
   4. Add a new pipe in /monetdb5/optimizer/opt_pipes.c

Comment: MonetDB doesn't automatically have a table called `sys`.  Which table are you looking for?  Also, afaik, \d only list user-created tables, not the system tables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For your first question: if your `current_schema` is not `sys`, you need to use `select sys.optimizer;`.

For your second question: the best existing example is probably in `monetdb5/extras/mal_optimizer_template`.  Next to that, it's basically checking the source code to see how other optimisers have been implemented.  NB, although it doesn't often happen, the internals of MonetDB can change between (major) versions. I'd recomment you to use Oct2020 or newer.

Answer (score 1):

Since Oct2020, variables now have a schema (to keep it other SQL objects). In your session, 'sys' is not the session's schema, that's why it cannot find the 'optimizer' variable, the same for the tables.

In default branch (will be available in the next release) I added a "schema path" property on the user to search SQL objects besides the current session's schema. By default it includes the 'sys' schema.

Answer (score 0):

Concerning your second question,

You also have to create and add an optimizer pipeline to `opt_pipes.c`. Look for the `default_pipe` and then copy/paste that one to a new pipeline and add your optimizer to it.

There are some more places where you might need to add your optimizer, like in the `codes[]`array in `opt_wrapper.c`. Just mimick one of the standard optimizers like `"reorder"`.

Comment: May I ask about the OPTwrapper function? It use **findSymbol** to get the MAL block of the optimizer(for example: costModel) and set **mb=s->def**. But then apply the optimizer to **mb**, is it use the optimizer to optimize itself rather than the MAL that's waiting to be optimized.

Comment: No mb is the actual MAL plan that is going to get optimized. OPTwrapper is just a generic wrapper that does some superficial checks such that the actual optimizer implementations do not have to be burdened by that boilerplate. As you can see, at some point we call
`msg = (str)(*(codes[i].fcn))(cntxt, mb, stk, 0);`
which is actually an optimizer that is going to try to optimize mb.

Comment: By the way, the case that you are referring to, is a more special case when the optimizer has a specific mal function signature as a parameter for which it needs to optimize its mal implementation. It has to look up the corresponding mal block by calling findSymbol first.